# The parentId do not set to the child entity automatically by cascade

Tags: hibernate, parent-child, cascade

In the entity Invoice, I have a set of DetailInvoice with cascade is ALL

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "invoice")
public Set<DetailInvoice> getDetailInvoices() {
    return detailInvoices;
}
```

In the entity DetailInvoice:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
public Invoice getInvoice() {
    return invoice;
}
```

Saving:

```
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    DetailInvoice detailInvoice = new DetailInvoice();
    invoice.getDetailInvoices().add(detailInvoice);
    detailInvoice.setInvoice(invoice); // (1) Should we need this row?
    session.save(invoice);
```

If we do not have a row (1), the detailInvoice will have invoiceId is null in database.
Why Hibernate do not setInvoiceId to detailInvoice automatically base on the annotation mapping?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to

[Hibernate 4.1 Documentation Section 1.2.6](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-associations-bidirectional)

The Person and Events example is something similar to what you are talking about.

Regards,

Shardul.

Comment: Thank for your answer but I think that document is not the answer for the question. That is just mention about the _inverse_ which is _mapBy_ declaration. The question relate to cascade and specify the parent for the list of child.

Comment: I meant this part

"First, keep in mind that Hibernate does not affect normal Java semantics. How did we create a link between a Person and an Event in the unidirectional example? You add an instance of Event to the collection of event references, of an instance of Person. If you want to make this link bi-directional, you have to do the same on the other side by adding a Person reference to the collection in an Event. This process of "setting the link on both sides" is absolutely necessary with bi-directional links."

It looks like you referred to section 1.2.5, refer to section 1.2.6